# How to set Image Height and Width Properties of Bitmap

Tags: c#

Pls. suggest how to set an image's width & Height Property while saving Images

Comment: You really need to provide more context here. What APIs are you using, for example?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to save bitmap with some specific width and height (which differ from the `Width` and `Height` properties of the bitmap), you need to create a new Bitmap of corresponding size and draw the initial bitmap in needed size on it.

Like this:

```
using (Bitmap bmpToSave = new Bitmap(1000, 500)) {
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpToSave)) {
        g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, 1000, 500);
    }
    bmpToSave.Save(@"bitmap.bmp");
}
```

Where `bmp` is your original bitmap.
Also, read up on some options that affect the quality of resampling if you need the high quality result.